# Change just the domain no matter where it exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have domain in my html page, that appears in several locations (in link, src, title, etc)

i need to change the domain name, for example instead of "Yahoo.com", to become "Morad.com" on the page load.

```
<title>yahoo.com</title> 
<script src="yahoo.com"></script>
<href>yahoo.com</href>
```

so my request, it's does not matter where this domain exist i need to replace it.

so i write this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var link = document.replace('Yahoo.com','Morad.com');
    )};
```

but that does not help.
can you please advise

Comment: You can't edit your HTML? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `document.body.textContent.replace("xyz.com", "abc.com");`

Comment: You need to do something that that `link =` (similar to above @ScottMarcus comment) - `.replace` doesn't change the source value, it gives you a new value with the replacements made)

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways also.

```
const blackList = [
    'script',
    'html',
    'body',
    'meta',
];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`*:not(${blackList.join(', ')})`);

function changeText(elms, text, replaceText) {
    text = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
    elms.forEach(elm => {
        if (text.test(elm.innerText)) {
            elm.innerText = replaceText;
        }
    });
}

changeText(elements, 'yahoo.com', 'Morad.com')
```